# (as3) sprite needs a child added to it to be visible, but only if I set alpha to 0?

Tags: actionscript-3

Flash version: 31.0.0.108

So I have a sprite, and through a mouse roll over I set the alpha to 0, and with a roll out I set it to 1.

If I don't have a child added to it, it won't reappear when I roll back out, but a trace shows the alpha does get set to 1.

If I do have a child added to it, (a textfield here) and the textfield isn't touching my sprite, it works like expected.

If it is touching the sprite, then when I mouse over again, only the part of the sprite in the textfield border will reappear.

And I just noticed this while typing - resizing the window at all will make it fully reappear.

And I don't have this problem at all if I set alpha to anything else, like 0.01. I do have it if I set it to 0.001, but the trace shows that this just sets it to 0.

Here is my code:

Main class:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import Menu;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var mainMenu:Menu = new Menu;
        private var playText:TextField = new TextField;

        public function Main() 
        {
            playText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

            playText.selectable = false;
            playText.text = "Play";

            playText.x = 660 - playText.width * 0.5;
            playText.y = 100;
            playText.border = true;

            mainMenu.addButton(600, 100, 120, 60, 0x914B00, playStart, playButtonOn, playButtonOff);
            mainMenu.buttonP.addChild(playText);

            function playButtonOn():void { mainMenu.buttonArray[0].alpha = 0.001; trace(mainMenu.buttonArray[0].alpha); }
            function playButtonOff():void { mainMenu.buttonArray[0].alpha = 1; }

            mainMenu.addMenu();
            addChild(mainMenu);

            function playStart():void 
            {
                mainMenu.removeMenu();
                removeChild(mainMenu);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Menu Class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Menu extends Sprite
    {
        public var buttonArray:Array = new Array;
        private var functionArray:Array = new Array;
        private var functionOnArray:Array = new Array;
        private var functionOffArray:Array = new Array;
        private var rollOnArray:Array = new Array;
        private var rollOffArray:Array = new Array;

        public var buttonP:Sprite;


        public function Menu() 
        {}

        public function addSprite(xPos:Number, yPos:Number, width:Number, height:Number, color:int):void 
        {
            var background:Sprite = new Sprite;
            background.graphics.beginFill(color);
            background.graphics.drawRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);
            background.graphics.endFill();  addChild(background); 
        }

        public function addButton(xPos:Number, yPos:Number, width:Number, height:Number, offColor:int, clickFunction:Function=null, rollOn:Function=null, rollOff:Function=null):void 
        {
            var button:Sprite = new Sprite;

            button.graphics.beginFill(offColor);
            button.graphics.drawRect(xPos, yPos, width, height);
            button.graphics.endFill();


            addChild(button);

            function mouseOn():void 
            {
                trace("on");
                if (rollOn != null) { rollOn(); }

                button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFunction);
                button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOn);
                button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOut);

            }

            function mouseOut():void 
            {
                if (rollOn != null) { rollOff(); trace("off");}

                button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFunction);
                button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOut);
                button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOn);
            }

            buttonP = button;
            buttonArray.push(button);
            functionArray.push(clickFunction);
            functionOnArray.push(mouseOn);
            functionOffArray.push(mouseOut);
            rollOnArray.push(rollOn);
            rollOffArray.push(rollOff);
        }


        public function removeMenu():void 
        {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) 
            {
                buttonArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionArray[i]);
                buttonArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, functionOnArray[i]);
                buttonArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, functionOffArray[i]);

                if (rollOnArray[i] != null) 
                {
                    buttonArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOnArray[i]);
                    buttonArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOffArray[i]);
                    rollOffArray[i]();
                }
            }
        }


        public function addMenu():void 
        {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) 
            { 
                buttonArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, functionOnArray[i]);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

edit:

**Menu class:**

**addSprite method:** just draws a new sprite. not relevant here

**addButton method:**
The method "addButton" draws a sprite, it has the name "button". The "mouseOn" and "mouseOff" functions just add and remove event listeners for eachother. mouseOn adds a "MouseEvent.CLICK" event listener for the parameter "clickFunction". 
and mouseOff removes it.

the "rollOn" parameter is just called when "mouseOn" is called. same for "rollOff" and "mouseOff"

All the array pushing at the end of this method is just pushing the functions onto an array for use in the "addMenu" and "removeMenu" functions. and "buttonP" is just a quick and easy way to access "button" from the main class.

**method removeMenu:**
Uses a loop to remove all event listeners that may have been added. (if i remove an eventlistener that hasn't been added, i think nothing happens. please tell me if i'm wrong.)

**method addMenu:**

uses a loop to add event listener for "mouseOn" for all the buttons. (functionOnArray is the array that mouseOn was pushed on)

**The main class:**

above the constructor:

mainMenu - i create a new "Menu"

playText - i create a new "TextField"

constructor:

I set up the textfield:

```
playText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

playText.selectable = false;
playText.text = "Play";

playText.x = 660 - playText.width * 0.5;
playText.y = 100;
playText.border = true;
```

I call the "addButton" method with "mainMenu":

```
mainMenu.addButton(600, 100, 120, 60, 0x914B00, playStart, playButtonOn, playButtonOff);
```

and i add "playText" as a child to the button I just created:

```
mainMenu.buttonP.addChild(playText)
```

The functions that are called when the button is moused over and moused off:
this is where changing the alpha "0.001" can fix the problem. 0.1, 0.01, 0.5, etc all make it work fine. but setting it to 0 gives the problem. (0.001 actually sets it to 0, as the trace shows.)

```
function playButtonOn():void {mainMenu.buttonArray[0].alpha = 0.001; trace(mainMenu.buttonArray[0].alpha); }
function playButtonOff():void {mainMenu.buttonArray[0].alpha = 1; }
```

call "addMenu" for mainMenu, add mainMenu as a child. and "playStart" is the function that's run when the button is clicked.

```
mainMenu.addMenu();
addChild(mainMenu);

function playStart():void 
{
    mainMenu.removeMenu();
    removeChild(mainMenu);
}
```

Comment: There are three things you should do about your post. 1. Edit your code so it complies with MCVE principle: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , all the better if you can provide a single piece of code that can be copy-pasted into an empty project to fully illustrate your problem, rather than pieces of your project that won't work without the other things from your project. 2. Format the code into readability. A lot of empty lines, several lines stacked into one, not readable. 3. The last piece of advice: don't define functions inside functions. That alone could make a great mess.

Comment: hey, ill edit the extra space out but its already as small as it can be. the problem only happens when i call the function through a class like this. And sorry about the functions inside functions, but I need them in there. I'll try to explain the code a bit better in an edit.

Comment: Please add Flash version and compiler version to this question. this doesn't sound well, and can potentially be local to an obsolete Flash version/build. (If I won't forget, I'll test this with FD and Flash 11.5)

Comment: flash version: 31.0.0.108 (idk if this is the right thing, i just found it with this site: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) and how do I find the compiler version? im using flashdevelop.